# UI for autocomplete and tabs with icon and text

Tags: html, css, angularjs, user-interface, angular-material

[image]

Hi Experts

My question is : 
how we can achieve UI as shown in above image using angular-material?

if it is not possible using angular-material then which framework I can use

1. The Tabs for FLight, Hotel, Buses, Holiday this kind of tab using icon and text with transparent background.
2. the search text boxes using autocomplete.

I am using angularJs and angular-material.

Any Help would be a great support.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the basic components you mentioned are available in angular material:

[Auto-complete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

[Tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)

You have also a lot of [icons](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/icon) But i suggest you though to use [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/?utm_source=hackernewsletter)

However for other things you asked, you have to absolutely learn [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) since no any framework can visually fit to your design choices.

Comment: using autocomplete and tabs not an issue. I want the css should exactly same as shown in the image above.

Comment: its not magic man. its just css. if you want it, just take a look to the css of these components. If you want exact the same, you can use the same framework they used too.